# I'm getting this JSONDecodeError at /vaccine/handle vaccine slots/ on heroku server but on my local server its working fine

Tags: python, json, django, api, heroku

**Heroku log**

```
2021-05-20T09:48:41.906814+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2021-05-20T09:48:41.907973+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.5.245.135 - - [20/May/2021:09:48:41 +0000] "POST /vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82617 "https://systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com/vaccine/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
2021-05-20T09:48:41.909232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/" host=systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com request_id=d4a0b644-a44b-435f-963a-6cf8eaa9a5da fwd="103.88.217.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=141ms status=500 bytes=82877 protocol=https
2021-05-20T09:49:27.945441+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.195.7 - - [20/May/2021:09:49:27 +0000] "GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +https://www.comscore.com/Web-Crawler)"
2021-05-20T09:49:27.946900+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logout/" host=systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com request_id=fdeb198f-21c1-4d20-913d-ee93134c5b07 fwd="18.232.161.22" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=395 protocol=https
2021-05-20T09:49:27.962588+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.195.7 - - [20/May/2021:09:49:27 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7748 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +https://www.comscore.com/Web-Crawler)"
2021-05-20T09:49:27.964058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/" host=systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com request_id=3fe99047-99a3-4d96-ad1f-087146838825 fwd="18.232.161.22" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=8282 protocol=https
2021-05-20T09:50:05.878286+00:00 heroku[run.9390]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2021-05-20T09:50:06.436547+00:00 heroku[run.9390]: Process exited with status 129
2021-05-20T09:50:06.537160+00:00 heroku[run.9390]: State changed from up to complete
2021-05-20T09:50:36.900551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/" host=systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com request_id=84aeeb06-fb0c-4802-910b-fc05d58fda52 fwd="103.88.217.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=126ms status=500 bytes=82891 protocol=https
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895526+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895536+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895537+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895537+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895547+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895547+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895548+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/vaccine/views.py", line 51, in handleVaccine
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895548+00:00 app[web.1]:     states = response.json()["states"]
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895549+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895549+00:00 app[web.1]:     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895550+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895550+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895550+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895551+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895551+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895552+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2021-05-20T09:50:36.895552+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
import json

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ast

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from django.contrib import messages
from vaccine.models import VaccineSlot


# Email settings

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='login')
def vaccineHome(request):
    return render(request, 'vaccine/vaccine_home.html')


def handleVaccine(request):
    # Write your STATE here!

    STATE_ID = 0
    # Write your DISTRICT here!
    DISTRICT_ID = 0
    # Setting AGE = 45 here in order to show the live notification demo
    AGE = 45  # Write the minimum age group for which you wanna get notified!
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
    }
    STATE_ID_ENDPOINT = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states"
    DISTRICT_ID_ENDPOINT = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/districts"
    ENDPOINT = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByDistrict"
    todays_date = datetime.now()
    DATE = f"{todays_date.day}-{todays_date.month}-{todays_date.year}"

    response = requests.get(f"{STATE_ID_ENDPOINT}", headers=headers)
    states = response.json()["states"]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        STATE = request.POST['state_name']
        DISTRICT = request.POST['district_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        AGE = request.POST['age']

        if len(STATE) < 2 or len(DISTRICT) < 2 or len(email) < 4 or isinstance(int(AGE), int) == False:
            messages.error(request, "Please fill up the form correctly!")
            return redirect('vaccine')

        else:

            # print(states)
            for state in states:

                if state["state_name"] == STATE:
                    STATE_ID = state["state_id"]
                    print(STATE_ID)
                    break

            if STATE_ID == 0:
                messages.error(request, f"There is no state named {STATE}")
                # print(f"There is no state named {STATE}")
                return redirect('vaccine')

            response = requests.get(
                f"{DISTRICT_ID_ENDPOINT}/{STATE_ID}", headers=headers)
            districts = response.json()["districts"]

            for district in districts:
                if district["district_name"] == DISTRICT:
                    DISTRICT_ID = district["district_id"]
                    print(DISTRICT_ID)
                    break

            if DISTRICT_ID == 0:
                messages.error(
                    request, f"There is no district named {DISTRICT} in state {STATE}")
                # print(f"There is no district named {DISTRICT} in state {STATE}")
                # exit()
                return redirect('vaccine')
            vaccine_enquiry = VaccineSlot(
                state_name=STATE, district_name=DISTRICT, age=int(AGE), email_notification=email)
            vaccine_enquiry.save()
            messages.success(
                request, "Your request has been successfully sent.")
    if check_vaccine(ENDPOINT, DISTRICT_ID, DATE,
                     headers, int(AGE), vaccine_enquiry, request):
        messages.info(
            request, f"HURRY! Vaccine is availabe for age {AGE}.Details of the centers has been sent to your mail id.")
    else:
        messages.warning(
            request, f"\nNO Slot Available in the district {DISTRICT} for age {AGE} in this week as of {DATE}.")

    return redirect('vaccine')

# Function for getting center names


def check_vaccine(ENDPOINT, DISTRICT_ID, DATE, headers, AGE, vaccine_enquiry, request):
    response = requests.get(
        f"{ENDPOINT}?district_id={DISTRICT_ID}&date={DATE}", headers=headers)

    vaccine_slots = response.json()
    print(vaccine_slots)

    slot_available = False
    center_count = 1
    slots_data = ""
    for center in vaccine_slots["centers"]:
        # print(center)
        for session in center["sessions"]:
            if session["min_age_limit"] <= AGE and len(session["slots"]) > 0 and session["available_capacity"] > 0:
                slot_available = True
                slots_data += f"\n{center_count}) {str(center['name'])} on {str(session['date'])}\nOpening Time:{str(center['from'])}\tClosing time: {str(center['to'])}\nCENTER ADDRESS: {str(center['address'])}\nSTATE NAME: {str(center['state_name'])}\nDISTRICT NAME: {str(center['district_name'])}\nPINCODE: {str(center['pincode'])}\nVACCINE: {session['vaccine']}\nAVAILABLE CAPACITY: DOSE 1 = {str(session['available_capacity_dose1'])}\tDOSE 2 = {str(session['available_capacity_dose2'])}\nMinimum Age Limit: {str(session['min_age_limit'])}\nFee Type: {str(center['fee_type'])}\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
                center_count += 1
                # print(f"Center Name\t{center['name']}")
                # print(f"Slots available\t{session['slots']}")
                # print("-----------------------------------")
                break

    if slot_available:
        notification_data = f"   HURRY! Vaccine is availabe for age {AGE} at these centers: {slots_data}"

        print(notification_data)
        context = {'slots': slots_data}
        subject = 'welcome to TASK world\'s Vaccine Notification '
        message = notification_data
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [vaccine_enquiry.email_notification]
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
        return True
    # notify.send(notification_data)
    else:

        notification_data = f"\nNO Slot Available in the district {vaccine_enquiry.district_name} for age {AGE} in this week as of {DATE}."
        print(notification_data)
        subject = 'welcome to TASK world\'s Vaccine Notification '
        message = notification_data
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [vaccine_enquiry.email_notification]
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails at the line

```
states = response.json()["states"]
```

with `response` being basically:

```
response = requests.get("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
```

When I visit this URL in my browser I get:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: ------------------------------------
```

Thus `response.json()` fails.

Comment: This is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/4F6yNJG.png Heroku probably sees something like that as well.

Comment: I really don't know what is happening. It is just working fine in my local host.

Comment: The way CDN works it can fail for some people while for other people it works. It also takes a while for change to appear. Either way this is something the website owner of `https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states` has to figure out. Nothing you can do as a consumer. You can try using proxies and VPNs or hosting it on different servers where the issue does not exist but that isn't an ideal solution since the failure might appear again. Maybe you can find a REST access that is not hidden behind a CDN.